# Get all users who have added a reaction to a message (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

In discord.js, how do I get all the users who have added a reaction to a message? (And then do something with their ID and tag etc.)
Below is what I thought it would be but it doesn't work, and I can't find anything to help me on the internet with what I'm searching.

```
var users = msg.reactions.resolve(messageID).users.cache;
 var userIDs = [];
 var userTags = [];
 
 users.forEach(user => {
    userIDs.push(user.id);
    userTags.push(user.tag);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, this is enough to help you out. However, this will now target a message with a specific string (aka, an old message)

```
var targetedMessage = "Whatever the string is of that specific old message";
var userIDs = [];
var userTags = [];

client.on("message", message => {
     //Alternate targeting technique
     /*if(message.content == "reactMe") {
          targetedMessage = message.id;
     }*/
     if(message.content == "whoReacted" && targetedMessage != null) {
          var theReactors = "Everyone who reacted was:";
          for(var i = 0; i < userIDs.length; i++) {
               theReactors = theReactors + ` <@${userIDs[i]}>`;
          }
          message.channel.send(theReactors);
     }

}

client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
     if(reaction.message.content == targetedMessage) {
          var reacted = false;
          for(var i = 0; i < userIDs.length; i++) {
               if(user.id == userIDs[i]) {
                    reacted = true;
               }
          }
          if(!reacted) {
                    userIDs.push(user.id);
                    userTags.push(user.tag);
          }
     }
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the users who have reacted to an already existing, old message.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the nicest way to do it:

```js
  let channel = await bot.channels.fetch(channelId)
  let message = await channel.messages.fetch(messageId)
  let reactions = await message.reactions.cache.first().users.fetch()
  reactions = reactions.toJSON()
  for(i = 0; i < reactions.length; i ++) console.log(reactions[i].id)
```